# How to decompose linear transformation into "lerp-able" products of rotation and scaling transforms?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, rotations, interpolation, svd

Given two linear transforms in 3D as a matrices $A_0,A_1 \in \mathbb{R}^{3 \times 3}$. I can [lerp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation) between them for any "time", $t \in [0,1]$ using an expression such as[$^1$](http://mesh.brown.edu/dgp/pdfs/Alexa-sg2002.pdf)
$$
A_t = \exp\left( (1-t) \log(A_0) + t \log(A_1)\right).
$$
This gives pleasing interpolations, such as in this example where $A_0 = I$ and $A_1 = \begin{bmatrix}1&-1&0\\0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$:

[image: lerping shear of a cube]

Now, consider that I'm not allowed to store or interpolate linear transformations directly. I [must](https://registry.khronos.org/glTF/specs/2.0/glTF-2.0.html#transformations) decompose each transform into a product of rotations and diagonal matrices (a.k.a., non-uniform scaling transforms). I.e., $A_0 = R_0^1 S_0^1 \dots R_0^n S_0^n$ and $A_1 = R_1^1 S_1^1 \dots R_1^n S_1^n$.

Interpolations will be conducted by [slerping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slerp#Quaternion_Slerp) rotations and linearly interpolating diagonal matrix entries.

**How can I emulate the linear interpolation above under these conditions?**

As an example of a poor solution, consider decomposing the input transformations using singular value decomposition:

$$
A = U S V^\top \\
A = \underbrace{\det{(U)}\ U}_{R^1} \  \underbrace{\det{(U)} \ S \ \det{(V)}}_{S^1} \ \underbrace{\det{(V)}\  V^\top}_{R^2} \\
A = R^1 S^1 R^2
$$
By construction, $R^1,R^2 \in SO(3)$ and $S^1$ is diagonal.

Slerping and lerping these transforms for the problem above via:

$$
A_t = \text{slerp}\left(R^1_0,R^1_1,t\right)\ \left((1-t) S^1_0 + t S^1_1\right)\ \text{slerp}\left(R^2_0,R^2_1,t\right) 
$$

produces an interpolation with the correct end-point values but wild behavior in between:

[image: svd based interpolation of transforms on a cube]

Is it fundamentally impossible to get a better interpolation? If not, would using more than two auxiliary rotations per transform help tame this interpolation?

Typically, I have a sequence of transforms $A_0,A_1,A_2, \dots$. So, another phrasing would be, given a decomposition for $A_0$ (i.e., all $R^i_0$ and $S^i_0$ are given) what values for the decomposition of $A_1$ would create the least-motion/least-work interpolation?

Comment: I edited your post because it was difficult to parse that the $|$'s were brackets for $|\cdot|$ expressions. I presume $|U|$ refers to the determinant of $U$ in this context (personally, I prefer $\det(U)$); perhaps this deserves an explicit statement.

Answer (score 1):

Another method to interpolate from $I$ to a matrix $A$ with $\det(A) > 0$: let $A = USV^T$ be an SVD. We can write
$$
A = \underbrace{UV^T}_{R_1}\ \  \underbrace{VSV^T}_B,
$$
noting that $R_1$ is guaranteed to be a rotation when $\det(A) > 0$.  Notably, $B = VSV^T$ is the spectral decomposition of a positive definite matrix. If $V$ is a rotation, then we're done. Otherwise, as below, we can take
$$
B = \underbrace{VD_\epsilon}_{R_2} \ S\ \underbrace{D_{\epsilon} V^T}_{R_3}.
$$
I believe that "slerping" preserves the property that $R_2$ and $R_3$ are inverses, which I suspect means that the choice of $D_\epsilon$ used here has no effect on the overall transformation.

---

An improvement to the approach below: denote
$$
D_{\epsilon}^x = \pmatrix{\epsilon &0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1},\quad
D_{\epsilon}^{y} = \pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&\epsilon&0\\0&0&1}, \quad 
D_{\epsilon}^{z} = \pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&\epsilon}.
$$
For each choice of $D_{\epsilon} \in \{D_{\epsilon}^x,D_\epsilon^y,D_\epsilon^z,\epsilon I\}$, the product
$$
A = U S V^T = \underbrace{U D_{|U|}}_{R^1}
\underbrace{D_{|U|}SD_{|V|}}_{S^1}
\underbrace{D_{|V|}V^T}_{R^2}
$$
is a suitable decomposition. I suspect that the "wildness" of the rotation is determined by the angle by which $R^1$ and $R^2$ rotate; a lower angle means a more parsimonious interpolation.

With that in mind, I suspect that a good heuristic for the best candidate $D_{\epsilon} \in \{D_{\epsilon}^x,D_\epsilon^y,D_\epsilon^z,\epsilon I\}$ is to choose the candidate for which the sum of the angle-cosines is maximized, i.e. the candidate for which
$$
\operatorname{tr}(UD_{|U|}) + \operatorname{tr}(D_{|V|}V^T)
$$
is maximized.

---

I suspect that using the SVD is a reasonable approach here, but that the particular way that you have chosen to make $U$ and $V$ into rotation matrices (i.e. by multiplying by their determinants) has led to this issue. I suggest the following alternative.

Define
$$
D_{\epsilon} = \pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&\epsilon}.
$$
Decompose $A$ as the product
$$
A = U S V^T = \underbrace{U D_{|U|}}_{R^1}
\underbrace{D_{|U|}SD_{|V|}}_{S^1}
\underbrace{D_{|V|}V^T}_{R^2}.
$$

Comment: This worked well for my shear tests but produces a wild interpolation when $A_0 = I$ and $A_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: That's surprising. What SVD did you get for $A_1$? Since $A_1$ is a rotation and $A_1 = A_1 \cdot I\cdot  I $ is an SVD, this should just come down to slerping a rotaiton

Comment: I get $A_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 & 0 \\ -1  & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \  I \  \begin{bmatrix} -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}^\top$

Comment: You could get two alternatives by switching $\epsilon$ to a different diagonal entry. For this particular case, replacing $D_{\epsilon}$ with
$$
\pmatrix{\epsilon & 0 & 0\\0 & 1 & 0\\0 & 0 & 1}
$$
should give us the "better" interpolation. So you could extend this approach to get 3 candidate interpolations, but there's still the question of how to choose the best of the 3

Comment: I think $V$ contains the information of which to use, but I'm not quite there yet. We know that the best fit rotation to $A$ is $U D_{|UV^\top|} V^\top$... I'm trying to force this to be $R^1$ and then handle the shear after.

Comment: @Alec That's an interesting thought. I have another, more "brute force" idea (see the latest edit); perhaps that's worth a try

Comment: Another approach that's tangentially related to your latest idea: we could find a rotation $R_1$ so that $A = R_1 S$, where $S$ is a symmetric matrix with either all non-negative eigenvalues or one negative eigenvalue. From there, we've "reduced the problem" to the case of $A = S$. That said, I'm not sure how to simplify the process using the fact that $S$ is symmetric.

Comment: Note that $S$ has a negative eigenvalue if and only if $A$ has a negative determinant. From your examples, it looks like $A$ always has a positive determinant. Is that true in general?

Comment: Not in general, but frequent enough that a solution for that specific case would still go a long way. (The improved approach is looking good so far; I continue to test)

Comment: It's notable that if $A_0$ and $A_1$ have determinants of opposite sign, then it is impossible to interpolate between them using invertible transformations, so perhaps their having the same sign is a reasonable assumption to stipulate

Comment: Yeah, I think that's mostly reasonable. The exp/log interpolation will fail. Although, linearly interpolating an $S_0$ and $S_1$ with opposite determinants will still produce something reasonable (albeit through a singularity).

Comment: Meanwhile, it seems a counter example to the improved solution happens with $A_1 = \begin{bmatrix}
1/2 & -\sqrt{1/2} & -1/2 \\
\sqrt{1/2} & 0 & \sqrt{1/2} \\
-1/2 & -\sqrt{1/2} & 1/2 \end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Interesting counterexample. It might help to add $D_\epsilon = \epsilon I$ to the list of candidates (which amounts to taking your original approach in certain cases)

Comment: I've also added another approach